# issue in creating docker image from docker file

Tags: docker

Created a Docker file in oreder to install Tomcat server from Unix as bashe os

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y #to update os
RUN apt-get dist-upgrade
RUN apt-get install build-essential
RUN apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk # to install java 8
RUN apt-get wget -y #to install wget package
RUN apt-get wget https://mirrors.estointernet.in/apache/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.37/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.37.tar.gz #to download tomcat 
RUN tar -xvzf apache-tomcat-9.0.37 # unzipping the tomcat
RUN mkdir tomcat # craeting tomacat directory
RUN cp apache-tomcat-9.0.37/* tomcat # copying tomact files to tomact directory
```

Command to create Docker Image from Docker file:

`docker build -t [img name] -f  [file name] .`

On execution, while installing java package am getting like this:
'''**After this operation, 242 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y**'''

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: You might find it easier to start from the [Docker Hub `tomcat` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/).

Comment: @DavidMaze that is a good point. They should use the `tomcat` image as the base image, and add their code on top from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the prompt because the command is awaiting user input for whether or not to install a package. The `-y` flag you're using for a few of them (like `wget`) allows `bash` to assume a yes. Add this flag to all your installation commands.

By the way, there's quite a few potential issues with the Dockerfile you posted.

For example, you have `RUN apt-get wget ...`

Are you sure that is what you want to do, and not just `RUN wget ...`? Unless `wget` is a command that `apt-get` takes, [which it isn't](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/apt/apt-get.8.en.html), it will cause unexpected behavior.

You also seem to be missing the command to start the Tomcat server, which can make it so that nothing happens when you attempt to run the image.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` when running the `apt-get` commands, something like this:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install build-essential -y
```

Also, it's considered bad practice to use multiple `RUN` steps which could be consolidated into one. More about Dockerfile best practices can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/).